# PyPDF2 insists on removing all the spaces

Tags: python, pypdf

I have read a number of other stackoverflow answers and have yet to find a satisfactory answer to this, but it has been asked before. When I attempt to use PyPDF2 to read pdf documents it merges all of the words in a sentences into one continous string. Has anyone made any progess in figuring out how to avoid this. Below is the code

```
 import PyPDF2
 import pandas as pd

 import  struct as struct

 from nltk import word_tokenize

 pdfFileObj = open("notes.pdf", 'rb')

  pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

 ## reading pages fine
 print(type(pdfReader.numPages))

## read in the pages 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)

 print(pageObj.extractText())
```

below is a sample of the output

```
2)Explanationofthedifferencebetweenprobabilityandstatistics.Theroleofprobability
instatisticaldecisionmaking.ExamplesoftheuseofProbabilityinStatistics.
3)Datasummarization(graphicalandnumerical)

4)Probabilityandrandomvariables
```

Answer (score 6):

Never figured out how to remove the spaces, it is a very unwieldy program. I found the answer to use pdfMiner to be the most helpful. It is easy to understand and there exists better documentation. Below is a link for anyone having the same issue as myself.

http://survivalengineer.blogspot.ie/2014/04/parsing-pdfs-in-python.html